# ayuda con error en visual Studio

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio

Hola tengo el siguiente problema en un proyecto de C# tengo 3 proyectos
y cuando ejecuto el programa me manda el siguiente error:

> Se han producido los siguientes errores al intentar cargar la aplicación.
>   - El atributo OwinStartup detectado del ensamblado 'API' que hace referencia al tipo de inicio 'API.Startup' entra en conflicto con el atributo del ensamblado 'BackEnd' que hace referencia al tipo de inicio 'BackEnd.Startup' porque tienen el mismo objeto FriendlyName ''. Quite uno de los atributos, cambie su nombre o haga referencia al tipo deseado directamente.
>   Para deshabilitar la detección de inicio de OWIN, agregue appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup con el valor "false" al archivo web.config.
>   Para especificar el ensamblado, clase o método de inicio de OWIN, agregue appSetting owin:AppStartup con la clase de inicio completa o el nombre del método de configuración al archivo web.config.

Ya agregué la línea `appSetting owin:AutomaticAppStartup` con el valor "`false`" al webconfig pero si la agrego me muestra este otro error:

> Se encontraron varios tipos que coinciden con el controlador 'Home'. Esto puede ocurrir si la ruta que atiende esta solicitud ('{controller}/{action}/{id}') no especifica espacios de nombres para buscar un controlador que coincida con la solicitud. En tal caso, registre esta ruta llamando a una sobrecarga del método 'MapRoute' que use un parámetro 'namespaces'.
>
> La solicitud de 'Home' encontró los siguientes controladores coincidentes:
>   API.Controllers.HomeController
>   BackEnd.Controllers.HomeController

¿Podrían echarme una mano? Gracias.

Answer (score 2):

después de leer ya encontré la solución, es un proyecto con 2 soluciones por lo tanto en el archivo routeconfig, puse lo siguiente para cada uno de las soluciones y funciona de maravilla.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
              namespaces: new[] { "API.Controllers" }
        );
```

y para el backend de la otra solución.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
             namespaces: new[] { "BackEnd.Controllers" }


        );
```

con eso se soluciono mi problema.

saludos.